# Increase in voltage on filter capacitor

Tags: power-supply, voltage, capacitor, charge

I am making a simple power supply that uses a transformer of 220 to 12-0-12, I am using the following diagram below:
[image]

The circuit gives +ve and -ve voltage. The problem is that as I turn switch on it gives +15V on +ve. As I turn it off and on again the voltage increases to +26V. The input voltage is same and still the voltage increases on capacitor. It increases again and again on switching. I haven't attached a resistor for discharge...but logically the voltage should increase as capacitor is in parallel between +ve and ground. Kindly help me??

Comment: (Polar?!) pF capacitors in a mains frequency filter look off. No load voltage can easily be 17 V with 230 V in; 26 V from C6 + to - (GND) is strange.